# Как скомпилировать .py в .exe с картинкой

Tags: python, компиляция

У меня есть скрипт с Tkinter , в котором есть фоновая картинка .
Как я могу скомпилировать этот скрипт так , чтобы картинка была вшита в exe файл . Что бы у меня был только один .exe файл и при открытии я сразу получал рабочую программу ? 
Сейчас скрипт не работает как только возле него нету картинки , либо в нужной директории нету картинки . Может есть команда для pyinstaller чтобы компилировать в один файл вместе со всеми используемыми файлами в скрипте